# css floated element position collapse when resized

Tags: css, css-float

Whenever I resize the browser, the 2nd div in .container positions below the first one.

```
<div class = "container">
     <div class = "one"></div>
     <div class = "two"></div>
</div>
```

The divs are really blank.

CSS

```
.container{
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 810px;
    min-width: 810px;
}
.one,.two{
    width: 300px;
    height: 450px;
}
.one{float:left}
```

Comment: @Deepanshu It's already a div.

Comment: float "two" left as well. Or maybe on container `display: inline`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just realized that, you are not floating the other element, this is causing it to shift down, you should use `float: left;` or `right` as it's a `div` so it will take up entire horizontal space, and hence it is pushed down.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/tykNw/)

```
.one, .two{
    width: 300px;
    height: 450px;
    float:left; /* Float both elements */
    background: #f00;
}
```

---

**Alternative**

You should use `display: inline-block;` and `white-space: nowrap;` to prevent the wrapping of the elements

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/xCeSg/)

This will gave you the same effect, the only thing is `4px` white space, you can simply use

```
.two {
   margin-left: -4px;
}
```

the above will fix the white space issue for you

[**Demo 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/xCeSg/1/)

Comment: inline-block is not supported by many browsers. Using float + margin in my opinion is better.

Comment: @mr.d what :O who told you inline block is not supported? http://caniuse.com/inline-block

Comment: I used to develop some mobile websites, viewed by old model devices, so I have the experience. As you can see in your link, many old mobile browsers do not support inline-block.

Comment: You just can not control what devices that viewers use.

Comment: @mr.d pheeew I don't wanna debate more on this but seriously there will be no issue if you use `display: inline-block;` and btw no one uses 1990's phone models anymore..

Comment: @Mr.Alien I already did your answer but it still pushes the .two below .one.

Comment: @user2586153 Did you saw the demos?

Comment: @Mr.Alien yes, I saw the demos. I implemented it but it still re-positions itself.

Comment: @Mr.Alien my mistake. I haven't uploaded it to server. It works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

Add this CSS. [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xCeSg/3/).

```
.two {
    margin-left: 300px;
}
```

PS: When works with float, you should [clearfix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8554043/what-is-clearfix).

Answer (score 0):

Give your body a minimum width:

```
body {
    min-width: 1110px;
}
```

Then, when the viewport gets smaller than 1110px the scrollbar will appear.

Note: if you add margin, padding or border to the divs, add it to the min-width of the body (or take some extra space).

Comment: shouldn't be the container have this attribute?

Comment: You could... Works too.